# How can I get back to Google Sign In / Account Chooser in a Phonegap/Cordova app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

Building my first app with PhoneGap Build but cannot solve a problem which is, of course, an important piece.

The app uses Google oAuth2 to access an external site where I fetch data with Ajax.  I use a url to do the initial login.

The only way I can get back to the Google Sign In is to delete and reinstall the app in iOS. In Android, I can use Application Manage and Clear Data.

In both cases, I get asked for the Sign In again as desired if I take either of those manual steps.

How can I programmatically clear the oAuth2 data which I believe is causing the problem?

Or, if necessary, what can I do to reinitialize the app entirely?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this to work for me:

```
    function googLogout (){
    var ref = window.open('https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=http://google.com', '_blank', 'hidden=yes');
    setTimeout(function(){ref.close();}, 3000); 
    alert('goog logout done');
}
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Hello @user1452893 I have one app that do google authentication but during login process it opens the new window for login but not coming bak to app. How you handle that thing please post anywhere or tell me here if it is short!

Comment: @0MV1 Sorry, not working on that code anymore. But, I think I did not have that issue because it was opened up in a new window ("_blank") so it didn't "go back" but just closed. Wish I could be more helpful.

Comment: Hello @user1452893 My question is, it opens the window in browser for authentication but after login / allow it goes to find the localhost://port/callback.html which I have defined in redirect_url but it can't find because I am running app in mobile so. Tell if I am wrong anywhere please refer the given link I have done the same thing as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135466/coming-url-doesnt-let-me-go-further-in-cordova-app-after-google-authentication?noredirect=1

Comment: Your problem may be with localhost. Try just calling the page.

Comment: I already try your suggestion but redirect_uri do not give me permission to post direct html page. It should be something www.example.com or localhost, it's a big confusion for me.