# Coming url doesn't let me go further in cordova app after google authentication

Tags: android, cordova, google-api, google-authentication

Hello I am using Cordova app using Visual Studio 2015 community and simply login in the app using google authentication it's pretty fine login is done by open it in new window but after login it gives me the three pop up messages and than don't do anything.

The messages are (which are coming after login process and gives allow permission):

> 1) gap_init:2
>
> 2) gap:[null,"CoreAndroid","messageChannel","CoreAndroid237153815"]
>
> 3) gap:[null,"CoreAndroid","show","CoreAndroid237153816"]

by pressing these messages as "OK" it's just showing me my first page in the same popup window from where I logged in using Google and returned url after login is:

http://localhost:4400/?code=4/chL63O9SMzMFZGOlqcB9TFMVUFxWj0E4GYEuVFDQ3gM#.

My configured url settings in console.developers.google.com are:

> Authorized JavaScript origins = http://localhost:4400
>
> Authorized redirect URIs = http://localhost:4400

and when I am calling the api in that in redirect_uri I pass localhost://4400

I am supposed to go on the second page after login and give allow permission i.e. index2.html but no such process takes place after window gets popped up.

In mobile it open's the browser but don't come back to application for further process staying there after allow process done and finding the coming url i.e.

http://localhost:4400/?code=4/chL63O9SMzMFZGOlqcB9TFMVUFxWj0E4GYEuVFDQ3gM#.

Where am I doing wrong please suggest me anyone as soon as possible. Thank you

Comment: redirect your url to the callback2auth.html instead of localhost:4400 (if you pass localhost) in console config as suggested by google and also pass that in redirect_url in your code where call google api. for issue of coming back I am working on it get back to you soon.

Comment: yes @0MV1 it is working for login thanks and waiting for the next issue of coming back to app

Answer (score 0):

IF you have placed cordova.php in root try reload after renaming it

Comment: Hello ricky, are you sure that (short) is the right answer to the problem ?

Comment: Hii Faisal I was getting same issue when I was trying to run run it on desktop. you can again change the name to cordova.php after you finish on you desktop.